# Javascript populate HTML table given cell data

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-table

I have an html table with cells that can be edited when clicked on. I am trying to figure out the best method to change cell data in cells following an edited cell.

For example, say the table comes populated by random numbers or letters. When I changed a cell to "14" I want the cells after it to change automatically to 15, 16, 17,n+1..ect. Or if I entered "h" the following cells would change to i,j,k,l...z stopping at z.

The number one seems pretty easy as I could just create a loop and `i++` for each cell. However, the letter one doesn't seem as simple. Would I need to create an alphabet array and find the edited cell letter within it then proceed to the end of the array inserting each into the follow cells?

Comment: What are you using to edit the cells?  I think you ought to consider using some sort of library such as jQuery plugin sheet (excel-like html tables, fully customizable) http://visop-dev.com/Project+jQuery.sheet

Comment: I am using this as a means to learn more javascript so I would prefer not to use a premade solution.

Answer (score 1):

This can actually be done with a fairly simple function call like this one:

```
function NextChar(c){
    return String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
}
```

where c is the alphabetic character that is entered into the cell, passed as a parameter.

I can see this question was done quite some time ago, so this answer is more for people who make come seeking answers later.

Answer (score 0):

I would make arrays with character sequences as you said and use the jQuery.inArray() API to detect which sequence the edited cells content is in.

Check it out: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/